# Does the $\mathrm{Spec}(F)$ equal $\overline{F}$ for a field $F$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and let $p\in F[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial. Let $P\in F[X]$ be an arbitrary polynomial. Does there exist a polynomial $Q\in F[X]$ such that $p(X)$ divides $Q(P(X))$, i.e.,
$$
Q(P(X))=p(X)R(X),\quad R\in F[X]?
$$
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is q(X)? Are there any conditions?

Comment: Is there a difference between $q$ and $Q$? Or is $q = p$?

Comment: Apologies. Will correct now.

Comment: $Spec(F[x]) = \overline{F} / Gal(\overline{F}/F)$, the size of the Galois orbit is the degree of the prime $p \in Spec(F[x])$. Your question is obvious : let $p(a) = 0$ then pick $Q$ such that $Q(P(a)) = 0$.

Comment: "let $p(a)=0$ then pick $Q$ such that $Q(P(a))=0$". My question is exactly whether this can be always done.

Comment: Pick a (non-constant) polynomial $Q \in F[x]$ having a root at $P(a)$. It can be done because $P(a)$ is algebraic over $F$.. And of course you need $P$ to be non-constant for $Q(P(X))$ to be non-constant. Concretely $F[P(a)]$ is a finite $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space so there is a $F$-linear relation between $1,P(a),P(a)^2,\ldots,P(a)^n$ which gives $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha_i$ be the roots of $p$ in $\overline F$, with multiplicities $m_i$. Let $\overline Q \in \overline F[X]$ be any polynomial for which $P(\alpha_i)$ is a root with multiplicity at least
$$\sum_{j : P(\alpha_j) = P(\alpha_i)} m_j$$
Then $p(X) \mid \overline Q(P(X))$.
Now $\overline Q$ has coefficients in some finite extension $E/F$. Multiply $\overline Q$ by all its conjugates w.r.t. this extension to obtain a $Q \in F[X]$ with the same property.

Comment: Conjugates.. this again leads to Galois theory which I don' t know. But I sort of see why it should work. Thank you.